# setAdapter in onLayoutChange

Tags: android

I need to use the value of the screen size so i am trying to set an adapter for my gridview like this

```
    @Override
public void onLayoutChange(View view, int left, int top, int right,
        int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
    Log.d("LayoutTest","left="+left+", top="+top+", right="+right+", bottom="+bottom);
    gridview.setAdapter(new GridImageAdapter(this,bottom));

}
```

This doesn't show anything in my grid view but if i move this line

```
gridview.setAdapter(new GridImageAdapter(this,1000));
```

to the onCreate method it works i don't understand why it doesn't work in the onLayoutChange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When gridview setAdapter it will request Layout to layout its children. When gridview layout (its children) the onLayoutChange function is called ... again.

references:http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.layout%28int%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29

And jump into gridView.setAdapter again.

First jump setAdapter it goes according to this cycle, but the 2nd I do not know why it is not happening.

However, if it takes place then your code becomes endless loop. So it did not relayout after setAdapter along with the gridView setAdapter removed_All_Children_InLayout -> the gridview display nothing.

Back to your problem, I think if you need the screen size, you should use the getResource ().GetDisplayMetrics(dm) and dm.widthPixels or dm.heightPixels OR another way to get screen size. DO Not use like you use, because it is potentially a lot of bugs.

But if you still want use OnLayoutChange, you should add a small code like:
if(gridview.getAdapter() == null) gridView.setAdapter(new GridImageAdapter(this,bottom));
(But I do not recommend :))